# Make page images and content responsive, wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site which is responsive. In my home page there is a slider (responsive slider) Now i need to add some content below the slider with a small image and a one sentence description. There will be 3rows, in 1st row i need 3 images with 3 small descriptions , in 2nd and 3rd row 2images with descriptions. I need to make these responsive. Images and the small description should be responsive. I tried so many ways , but nothing works. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: list what you have tried. there are loads of tutorials about responsive design (% widths, % margins). Text is impossible to make responsive at the moment so you use media queries for the different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive layout design is 99.9% to do with your css and how you're writing it. Can you post any code examples? What theme are you using?

Some theme designers like Woothemes provide shortcodes for adding columns and rows of content that work responsively out of the box.

It's impossible to help any further until you provide more information :-)